# datawindow can not retrieve records on sql server 2008 R2 with powerbuilder 12.5

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2008-r2, records

As you have seen the title of this question, I have a Windows 7 running with SQL SERVER 2008 R2 and Powerbuilder Classic 12.5

I want to enter a simple text and use that text as a parameter to perform a LIKE statement inside the Datawindows. The search is really simple and it work great for me when using former databases like SQL SERVER 2000 or 2005.

I dont have a clue whats wrong here now but if I go to the SQL SERVER 2008 r2 console I can run the SQL statements using LIKE, but if I go back to Powerbuilder and try to run the program from there, simply the program do not return even one row.

Any clue? maybe some configuration to do on Power Builder 12.5 or SQL SERVER 2008 R2 side?

Need help with this.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute..  You said this worked fine with SQL 2000/2005?  Why not use that as your starting point?  You know you can place your SQL 2008 in SQL 200 compatibility mode?  The other thing is, when asking your question, it may prove to be helpful to provide what you are already are/were using - otherwise, we are guessing a bit when trying to answer your question.

At a high-level, it does appear something is not working with a RecordSet or ResulSet.

Comment: The thing is that I need to run especifically SQL SERVER 2008 R2 in this case. Do you think it has to deal with a configuration to do on SQL SERVER 2008 R2 or Powerbuilder 12.5 as well? Maybe a character set to value to change in the database? Thanks!

Comment: I just need Powerbuilder to run a datawindow with SQL LIKE instruction. Why not on SQL SERVER 2008 R2? I know for sure is a database issue.